# Which transaction manger to be used in Spring JPA Eclipselink with JTA enabled

Tags: spring, websphere, eclipselink, spring-transactions, jta

I'm using Spring 4.0, EclipseLink 2.6.3 with JPA 2.0 and IBM Websphere 8.5.5.8 with JTA enabled (Oracle 11g).

As of now my app is configured with **WebSphereUowTransactionManager** as my server/ container is Websphere like below.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"></bean>
```

When I was referring to this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.6/reference/transaction.html) from spring doc's in the ***8.9.1. Use of the wrong transaction manager for a specific DataSource*** section it says

> If you are using global transactions, you must use the Spring
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager for all your
>   for all your transactional operations. Otherwise Spring will attempt
>   to perform local transactions on resources such as container
>   DataSources.

What does it mean ? Should I shift to **org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager** as I'm using Spring @Transactional attributes in my services and DAO's ? Please advice.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned by @JBNizet its a super class extend by different vendor specific Transaction managers.In that case when should I use **org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager** ? How is it different from others ?

Comment: WebSphereUowTransactionManager **is** a JtaTransactionManager. http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/WebSphereUowTransactionManager.html

Comment: Agreed ! But I'm worried about exceptions thrown  by Spring transactions which are again wrapped by Websphere transaction manager